# Is it possible to change the background-color of a single link and change the provide properties for a:link?

Tags: css, background-color

I want to set the background-color of this `<ul>` to none.

But at the same time, I have set the link's background-color to black.

```css
a:link {
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="navg">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Help me.

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff - you can target specific links by using classes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors - you might have a read through the first steps link in the left column to get better knowledge of css

Answer (score 0):

Set the css property for ul tag like:

div ul.navg {background-color: transparent;}

or

div ul.navg {background: none;}

Comment: Make sure to add code tags around the css